# VBA Copying from changing date file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue I hope you can assist me with. 
I need to copy 5 files into one, the challenge though is the files is named after the dates they were created.

eg. file names could be;

```
TTDU 20191113 (for today).
TTDU 20191112
TTDU 20191111
etc.
```

(TTDU is name of the report and will never change)
Is there a way to create a line of code, where it subtracts -1 day from file name? And can it work for workdays and not include weekend?
Or maybe you have an idea how to do it in another way

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include the code you are working on in your question.

Comment: @braX sorry but so far I only have the whole macro to create the template for my file from a SAP script. However, I just need to include in the code to copy from these five sheets. My current macro won't help on this matter, as it only creates the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines, using `split` and `mid`

Called like so

`SortDateOut("TTDU 20191123")`

```
Function SortDateOut(strInput As String) As Date

Dim s As String

s = Split(strInput, Chr(32))(1)

SortDateOut = DateSerial(Mid(s, 1, 4), Mid(s, 5, 2), Mid(s, 7, 2))

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks im gonna try that out!